# How a simpler derive is written in R by group (in R, ggplot, dplyr, tidyverse)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, statistics

I have two datas in one column by their name in y axis, and a datetime in x axis.

I try to calculate numeric deriv for each two datas,  but I don't understand derive in R. (I've looking for `stats::D` or  `diff` but It doesn't work).

> f(x)=(t_n-t_n-1)/(date_time_n / date_time_n -1)

where f(x) will be my calc column.

ie to replace my `calc=t/10`, in the code below, by a function doing this. (I would prefer tidyverse /  dplyr)

Links

- [Calculate the derivative of a data-function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081737/10489562)
- My previous question [To add a legend by shape in ggplot ( added 2nd question after: to calculate numeric deriv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020350/1to-add-a-legend-by-shape-in-ggplot-2-and-to-calculate-numeric-deriv)

Below : ggplot picture of `calc=t/10` where `calc`  will be replaced by the derive.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

datas<-data.frame(
  t = c(
    50 + c(0, cumsum(runif(9, -7, 7))),
    70 + c(0, cumsum(runif(9, -10, 10)))
  ),
  orig=c(rep("s1",10),rep("s2",10)),
  date_heure = rep(
    seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="UTC"),by="hour", length=10) ,
    2
  ) 
)


datas<- (datas 
         %>% mutate (
           calc=t/10
         )
)


(
  ggplot(datas) 
  +   geom_line(mapping=aes(x = date_heure, y = t, color=orig, linetype = "s1"))
  +   geom_line(mapping=aes(x = date_heure, y = calc, color=orig, linetype = "s2"))
  +   scale_y_continuous(name = "t", sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~(range(datas$calc)), name = "calc"))
  +   geom_point(mapping = aes(x = date_heure, y = calc, color=orig), shape = 21, fill = "white")
  +   scale_color_manual(name = "calc", values=c("red", "blue"))
  +   scale_linetype_manual(name = "orig", values = c('solid', 'solid'), 
                            guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=c("red", "blue"))))

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want `calc` to be computed using the current and previous `t` and `date_heure` values. To get the value of a previous row in a particular column, you can use `lag`, as follows:

```
datas<- (datas
         %>% mutate (
           calc = (t - lag(t)) / as.integer((date_heure - lag(date_heure)))
        )
)
```

Please note that the value of `calc` for the first row is going to be `NA`. Hence, you may need to skip and give it a default value before you plot your figure.

For example:

```
datas <- datas[-1,]  # To skip the first `NA` value
datas[1,]$calc <- 0  # To give it a default value of `0`
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works and the datas and the plot seems like my user talk about it. I will accept as soon as my user have seen it in some days (~Tuesday ).

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you. You may give my answer an upvote for now and then accept it later :-)

Comment: Thank you. It seems ok...I validate. (I've deleted the comments about ggplot and plotly not accurate for this questions).

Answer (score 0):

The following lines will add a new row with the lagged time values per group.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- 
    data %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    mutate(lag.value = dplyr::lag(value, n = 1, default = NA))
```

Similarly, you could add another column where you calculate the 1st (forward) difference coefficient by a formula of your choice. Please note that if you have `NA` values, things might become more complicated.

More explanations and alternative approaches you find at [How to create a lag variable within each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291988/how-to-create-a-lag-variable-within-each-group)

Comment: Thank you but could you modify your code with my variable if you want I accept your answer. I tried `datas <-( datas %>% group_by(orig) %>% mutate(calc = dplyr::lag(t, n = 1, default = NA)))`, it displays datas but ggplot doesn't work.

Comment: To accept your answer I have also to wait the answer of my user in some days.

Comment: Thanks for the link.