# Select data and name when pointing it chart with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplotly

I did everything in ggplot, and it was everything working well. Now I need it to show data when I point a datapoint. In this example, the model (to identify point), and the disp and wt ( data in axis).
For this I added the shape (same shape, I do not actually want different shapes) to model data. and asked ggplot not to show shape in legend. Then I convert to plotly. I succeeded in showing the data when I point the circles, but now I am having problems with the legend showing colors and shapes separated with a comma...

I did not wanted to make it again from scrach in plotly as I have no experience in plotly, and this is part of a much larger shiny project, where the chart adjust automatically the axis scales and adds trend lines the the chart among other things (I did not include for simplicity) that I do not know how to do it in plotly.

Many thanks in advance. I have tried a million ways for a couple of days now, and did not succeed.

```
# choose mtcars data and add rowname as column  as I want to link it to shapes in ggplot
data1 <- mtcars
data1$model <- rownames(mtcars)
# I turn cyl data to character as when charting it showed (Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale)
data1$cyl <- as.character(data1$cyl)

# linking colors with cylinders and shapes with models
ccolor <- c("#E57373","purple","green")
cylin <- c(6,4,8)  
# I actually do not want shapes to be different, only want to show data of model when I point the data point. 
models <- data1$model
sshapes <- rep(16,length(models)) 


# I am going to chart, do not want legend to show shape
graff <- ggplot(data1,aes(x=disp, y=wt,shape=model,col=cyl)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  ylab ("eje y") + xlab('eje x') +
  scale_color_manual(values= ccolor, breaks= cylin)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = sshapes, breaks = models)+
  guides(shape='none') # do not want shapes to show in legend

graff
```

[chart is fine, but when converting to ggplotly, I am having trouble with the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikydi.png)

```
# chart is fine, but when converting to ggplotly, I am having trouble with the legend

graffPP <- ggplotly(graff)
graffPP
```

[legend is not the same as it was in ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTuNF.png)

I succeeded in showing the model and data from axis when I point a datapoint in the chart... but now I am having problems with the legend....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no easy out-of-the box solution to achieve your desired result.

Using pure `plotly` you could achieve your result by assigning `legendgroup`s which TBMK is not available using `ggplotly`. However, you could assign the legend groups manually by manipulating the `plotly` object returned by `ggplotly`.

Adapting my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69290220/12993861) post to your case you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = disp, y = wt, shape = model, col = cyl)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  ylab("eje y") +
  xlab("eje x") +
  scale_color_manual(values = ccolor, breaks = cylin) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = sshapes, breaks = models) +
  guides(shape = "none")

gp <- ggplotly(p = p)

# Get the names of the legend entries
df <- data.frame(id = seq_along(gp$x$data), legend_entries = unlist(lapply(gp$x$data, `[[`, "name")))

# Extract the group identifier, i.e. the number of cylinders from the legend entries
df$legend_group <- gsub("^\\((\\d+).*?\\)", "\\1", df$legend_entries)

# Add an indicator for the first entry per group
df$is_first <- !duplicated(df$legend_group)

for (i in df$id) {
  # Is the layer the first entry of the group?
  is_first <- df$is_first[[i]]
  # Assign the group identifier to the name and legendgroup arguments
  gp$x$data[[i]]$name <- df$legend_group[[i]]
  gp$x$data[[i]]$legendgroup <- gp$x$data[[i]]$name
  # Show the legend only for the first layer of the group 
  if (!is_first) gp$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE
}
gp
```

[image]